# How can I have a variable within a string?

Tags: google-apps-script

This code

```
var first = First name;
var body = 'Test1' first 'Test2';
```

gives me this error

```
Missing ; before the statement. (line 9, file "Code")
```

I am assuming that the end of the first test is being considered as the end of the variable so it wants to see a ;. Does anyone know how I can make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the strings, which can be simply done using '+', to display a string variable within another string.
The first line is also invalid, and assuming it is meant to be a single string, the fixed code should be:

```
var first = 'First name';
var body = 'Test1' + first + 'Test2';
```

Resulting in body = 'Test1First nameTest2'. Also note that spaces are not added between strings/variables automatically.
To add spaces, simply add them to the stings:

```
var body = 'Test1 ' + first + ' Test2';
```

Or add them as separate strings/variables:

```
var space = ' ';
var body = 'Test1' + ' ' + first + space + 'Test2';
```

Comment: Thank you so much I feel dumb for not knowing how to do it. By any chance do you know how to add spaces between them?

Comment: Answer changed to add spaces